# Appending tags to a row in a MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, database, tags

I'm generally a front end developer (HTML/CSS etc) but currently getting my chops stuck into some back end development for a challenge. Please bear in mind I've only been doing this back-end thing for a few weeks so my terminology / logic is in its infancy... Go easy ;)

As a starting point, I'm building a thing in PHP & MySQL so I can catalogue my vinyl collection. It's a really simple form that takes artist, title, label etc and stores that into a MySQL db.  I also want to implement tags for each record so one track might be tagged 'House | funky | vocal' whilst another would be tagged 'dubstep | MC | Bass' or something like that.

I can't store these tags as an array in MySQL so I understand that I need to insert them as a comma separated value and then when I want to work with these at a front-end level, I need to pull the CSV out of the database, EXPLODE that value and display each element as a separate list element.

That part I understand.  But how do I go about adding additional tags? I can't seem to find a definitive answer (maybe I'm searching the wrong thing?) but so far, all I can work out is that I'd have to take the current database value of 'tags' from the db and store that as a variable. Delete the 'tags' value from the db, append a new tag to the variable and then store the new variable back into the database.

Surely there's an easier way though?

Comment: `so I understand that I need to insert them as a comma separated value` That's the last thing you would really want to do. You could simply store those tags row by row in a table and then fetch all of them for your PHP code. Shouldn't be storing those tags like a CSV in one row

Comment: can you show us some code what you have tried and exactly where you are getting error.

Comment: Hanky Panky, thanks! Coming at this as a complete newbie, it's these golden nuggets of info that really do help!

Comment: Suresh, I'm not getting an error, nor do I have some code to show. I was asking more about the process of adding tags to a list already stored in a db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should study up on the concept of relation tables and foreign keys. You would be better breaking up the tags into its own table, something like this:

Album table

> ```
> album_id  album_artist    album_title
> ---------------------------------------------------
> 1         Nirvana         In Utero
> 2         Noisia          Split the Atom
> ```

Tags table

> ```
> album_id  tag
> --------------------------------------------------
> 1         Rock
> 1         Grunge
> 1         Alternative
> 2         Dubstep
> 2         Drum & Bass
> 2         Experimental
> ```

Then you can join them back into a comma delimited list using GROUP CONCAT

```
SELECT       a.album_artist
            ,a.album_title
            ,GROUP_CONCAT(b.tag) AS tags
FROM        Album a
JOIN        Tags b
USING       (album_id)
WHERE       album_id = xxx
```

results:

> ```
> album_artist    album_title       tags
> ---------------------------------------------------
> Nirvana         In Utero          Rock, Grunge, Alternative
> Noisia          Split the Atom    Dubstep, Drum & Bass, Experimental
> ```

You could further break up the data into an artists table, where the album_artist name is replaced by the artist id in the artists table, and the tag names are separated into another table and the tag names are replaced with the tag_ids...

Note that `GROUP_CONCAT` is specific to MySQL... Pretty sure SQL SERVER 2005 and later has something similar but I don't remember what they call it. Also `USING (col_name)` is MySQL specific, its just an easier way of writing an ON clause like  `ON a.album_id = b.album_id`  and can only be used when the joining columns have the same name. I just prefer `USING` to `ON` because its shorter and makes complicated queries more readable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

**Edit**
Per your comment, here is what it would look like if you broke tags off into its own table. I added 2 more entries to show value repetition - notice how Rock, Dubstep and Experimental are used more than 1 time but their text values are only listed once...

> ```
> Album table:
>
> album_id  album_artist        album_title
> ---------------------------------------------------
> 1     Nirvana                 In Utero
> 2     Noisia                  Split the Atom
> 3     Nero                    Welcome Reality
> 4     Pink Floyd              The Wall
>
> Tags table:
>
> tag_id    tag
> --------------------------------------------------
> 1         Rock
> 2         Grunge
> 3         Alternative
> 4         Dubstep
> 5         Drum & Bass
> 6         Experimental
>
> Album_Tags table:
>
> album_id  tag_id
> --------------------------------------------------
> 1         1
> 1         2
> 1         3
> 2         4
> 2         5
> 2         6
> 3         4
> 4         1
> 4         6
> ```

Query:

```
SELECT       a.album_artist
            ,a.album_title
            GROUP CONCAT(c.tag) AS tags
FROM        Album a
JOIN        Tags b
USING       (album_id)
JOIN        Album_Tags c
USING       (tag_id)
WHERE       album_id = xxx
ORDER BY    album_title ASC
```

Results:

> ```
> album_artist  album_title         tags
> ---------------------------------------------------
> Nirvana       In Utero            Rock, Grunge, Alternative
> Noisia        Split the Atom      Dubstep, Drum & Bass, Experimental
> Pink Floyd    The Wall            Rock, Experimental
> Nero          Welcome Reality     Dubstep
> ```

Comment: 3 general comments on understanding normalization and database design: If you're stuffing more than 1 piece of information into a column value, you're doing it wrong. If you find you're repeating information over and over, you're doing it wrong. If you find you columns with mostly NULL or empty values, you're doing it wrong. Of course there are exceptions to these rules but for proper database storage, you can't think in terms of excel spreadsheets... Many to Many relationships don't work that way

Comment: Thanks WebChemist. That's given me some great advice.  Just one comment on your tags table example. Say I had several albums under 'Rock', would I assign rock multiple times under 'tag' linked to the unique 'album_id'? I'm guessing that's the right way to do it instead of 'stuffing more than 1 piece of info into a column value'?

Comment: I would rename tags to album_tags, then make a tags table that just has tag_id, tag_name... so say in tags "Rock" has an id of 3, everywhere in the album_tags table you would list the value 3 instead of the word "Rock". If you link your table columns with foreign keys, then it will restrict ids to only the values in the other table (making sure you don't have records that dont have associated values). Also this makes updating a breeze, since if you wanted to change "Rock" to "Hard Rock" you only update the 1 tags entry, not EVERY album entry

Comment: Besides the wealth of info here on Stack Overflow about foreign keys and relation tables, there is a dedicated database stack exchange http://dba.stackexchange.com/ I think you will find they are much more helpful when it comes to answering conceptual database design questions where as SO focuses more on specific coding problems (and not having code to show often gets you closed as not a real question).